# i installed maven in my locale. i was run the demositecommerce project but i get the exception

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

i  installed maven in my locale. i was run the demositecommerce project but i get the exception

my maven paths are:
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
M2_HOME:C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.1
PATH:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin;

whenever i run the jetty-demo i get the Exception

cause Exception:

Buildfile: C:\eclipse-workspace\DemoSite\site\build.xml
start-db:
     [echo] Starting Data Base...
jetty-demo:
[artifact:mvn] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[artifact:mvn] -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
[artifact:mvn] Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds

how can i solve this  pls tell me

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem with `Maven 3.3` projects run from Eclipse which can be fixed by explicitly passing the **maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory** property to the JVM.

So in your case, to fix this error, try to edit the `jetty-demo` ant task in your `site/build.xml` file and add the following JVM argument:

```
<jvmarg value="-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME" />
```